# Logo doesn't appear on Ipad pro with Helix3 template

Tags: helix3

My website (www.fischer-club.ch) uses the Helix3 template.
The logo on the top does appear on desktops and on my Iphone. By resizing the desktop window, the logo stays always visbile.
I discover recently, that the logo doesn't appear on Ipad pro. I've tried with safari, chrome and firefox, no browser shows the logo.

Thanx for any help!

Comment: It's hidden due to your media query: `@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) { ... }` which is targetting the `pixel-ratio`. I'd probably suggest contacting the developer of Helix to notify them of the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Uploading a retina logo in Helix3 did the job! Thanks to your answer i now understand the purpose of the retina logo :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Please would you mind adding your solution as a proper answer below and mark it as accepted, so that other who potentially have the same issue can easily check the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Ipad pro has a retina display, so that it's necessary to configure a retina logo in the Helix3 template!